# Steps to design a Molex connectors in ALTIUM for PCB design. Help!

Tags: pcb, altium, circuit-design

I would like to design 2 molex connectors in Altium. Haven't done such connectors before and struggling hard to find my feet. I'm confused with the dimensions too. I'm attaching the both the data sheets below. Please have a look and guide me a simple and quick way to do it.

If anyone got libraries then that would be a great help too.

Thanks

Please find the attached

**[Datasheet 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ovohubomzxq5hnd/015921040_sd__J1.pdf?dl=0)**

### **[Datasheet 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cw8tpv8c3c305b6/716612040_sd__J2.pdf?dl=0)**

OK Guys. Sorry, for not being very clear in my question. But however much appreciated for your answers. Pretty much I'm aware of all the answers. And also thank you for the youtube video and molex libraries however video don't explain about mechanical dimensions very clearly and molex libraries don't have my part no..

I'm attaching where I'm stuck and how to proceed further. This pic is what I'm so far in altium.

[image: My Altium Work]

This one is actual dimensions from data sheet.

[image: Dimensions as per datasheet]

All the units are inch/mm. I'm doing in mils which is 1inch=1000mil. I've done the mechanical holes and pasted the pads as array and now not sure how to proceed further. Hope I made it clear this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add schematic and footprint library to your project. You can draw project-specific libraries in the PcbPrj, or create a library across multiple projects using the IntLib project.
2. Add a footprint. Then use your mechanical engineering skills to convert 2D datasheet drawings to something in Altium.
3. Go to molex.com (or other mfgr, alternatively 3dcontentcentral) and download a 3D model of your footprint, place it on your footprint and check if it aligns. This is optional but a nice sanity check + eye candy.
4. Create a schematic symbol, draw a symbol to your style.
5. Go to properties of the component and add the footprint.
6. (Only for IntLib) Recompile the library to produce and output IntLib file.

This is simple and quick. Searching for libraries is not simple and quick. It's best to learn yourselves the skills to draw your own components.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a tutorial for creating Altium libraries and posted it to YouTube not too long ago. I think it might help you out. It describes how to put together a schematic library and a PCB library, and how to link them together. Here's the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kyY25CGJtM

That will walk you through the process of creating your own libraries.

Here's the gist:

Create your schematic. During the creation, take careful not that your pin numbers are correct. They are what will link the correct footprint pads to the correct pins in the schematic. When the schematic component is correct, start your footprint. Follow the datasheet. Make sure that your hole sizes match the ones called out in the datasheet. The pad sizes need to be as big as they can be without colliding. The pads shown in the image in your post are colliding, and that is not ok. They are shorting together. Make sure each pad is separate from the next. Once your footprint is completed and saved under a unique name, then you need to link your footprint to your schematic. Go back to your schematic library and double-click the component (not in the editor, but in the SCH Library panel). At the bottom right of the window that pops up, in the "Models" pane, click the button that says "Add...". Select "Footprint", and then browse for the footprint you just saved. Once added, the pads will be linked to the schematic pins based on the pin numbers and the pad numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the video. I did find it at the first and it help me up to some extent. But in the video you said you will not be bothering much about exact coordinates and dimensions.I guess thats where I got stuck now.

Comment: At what timestamp in the video did I say I wouldn't bother with exact coordinates and dimensions? I'll try to clarify if you can point me to the exact place you got lost.

Comment: @i0s I have edited my answer to be a bit more specific. Let me know if you have any more questions or need more clarification